# How to insert <button> inside <li>from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put a button inline with text, like [image]

I am doing anything like:

```
    var list = document.getElementById('listaUnidadesCanjeadasAgregadas');
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    var btnDlt = document.createElement('button');

    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputSerie.val()));
    list.appendChild(entry);

    btnDlt.className = "btn-delete btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash";
    list.appendChild(btnDlt);
```

but its not the same because the image appears below the text
[image]

Forget the blue backgroud, its not important! Thank you people.

Comment: You're appending your button to the list, but you should be appending to the entry `entry.appendChild(btnDlt);` (buttons are not valid children of `ul` elements)

Comment: That is i what i wanted. Thx @pilchard! I am learning html, css and js. Regards

Comment: you are using bootstrp 3 ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  way1

```js
var list = document.getElementById('listaUnidadesCanjeadasAgregadas');
var entry = document.createElement('li');
var btnDlt = document.createElement('button');
btnDlt.className = "";//Class
list.appendChild(btnDlt);
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode('valor'));
entry.appendChild(btnDlt);
list.appendChild(entry);
```

```html
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <ul id =listaUnidadesCanjeadasAgregadas>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `button` elements are not valid children of `ul` elements, it should be appended to the `li`

Comment: You are appending the button to the list and then later appending to the item, clean up your code.

Answer (score 2):

last line

```
 list.appendChild(btnDlt);
```

you are appending to the list instead of the `entry`

try

```
 entry.appendChild(btnDlt);
```